# Intel Fortran compiler

Tags: xubuntu, compiler, fortran

I want to install a second compiler for fortran in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS distribution, but I do not have any idea. Currently I have gfortran compiler. What is the best way to install an Intel Fortran compiler in my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS distribution?

Answer (score 1):

The Intel Fortran Compiler is available on 30 day trial as a part of their Parallel Studio XE at https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compilers/choose-download.  Students and teachers can qualify for a free license.